# Увеличение картинки в материале кликом

Tags: joomla, cms

Здравствуйте!
Как можно сделать, чтобы картинка, обтекаемая текстом в теле статьи, при клике по ней увеличивалась, как бы выезжая вперёд, а при повторном клике - обратно?

Comment: @rust34, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Очень просто. Вам нужен редактор **JCE**, если вы еще не слышали о таком - настоятельно рекомендую установить.
После этого, кликаете по картинке в статье, вешаете на нее ссылку. В поле ссылка нужно прописать путь к картинке, например *images/content/lololo.jpg*. А во вкладке "**Всплывающее Окна**" выбрать **JCE MediaBox Popups**.

Answer (score 0):

С помощью Javascript.

Довольно неплохой скрипт для этого:
http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

Устанавливаете плагин Mavik Thumbnails, и изображения будут открываться так, как вам нужно. Только это не работает для изображений, которые вы вставляете изначально в полном размере. В общем, пробуйте.